# How can I convert unsigned int to unsigned char

Tags: c++, microcontroller

I'm trying to interface a digital sensor module to an Arm Cortex M4F chip.

The data received is 3 bytes from the module. However the only function I have available in my MCU is a uint32_t read function. I don't know why there isn't a uint8_t function but maybe it's just a matter of shifting bits? I'm learning c++ as I go here.

So i read the value as:

```
uint32_t value = mcu_read(pin);
```

`value` now contains an `uint32_t`, 4 bytes. I need the first three. Is it possible to shift it in any way to "extract" them out?
Does this make sense? The showstopper is the mcu_read function that reads 4 bytes minimum. If there where a `uint8_t` read function I could just call it three times to get the data I needed.

Comment: It might be easier to mask the uninteresting byte to 0 and keep the value in a uint32_t instead of dealing with 3 separate values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
uint32_t value = mcu_read(pin);
uint8_t* bytes = (uint8_t*)(&value);
uint8_t byte_0 = bytes[0];
uint8_t byte_1 = bytes[1];
uint8_t byte_2 = bytes[2];
uint8_t byte_3 = bytes[3];
```

**Be careful with endianess**

Comment: I did not think about it like that!

Comment: There are two 'fun' parts of endianness - order of bytes in a word and order of bits in a byte.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken this violates strict aliasing rules, since the exception only applies to `char` and not its aliases.

Comment: @Voo `uint8_t` should be a character type (this is not actually guaranteed by the standard but it is on all implementations that exist, and in practice it is a safe assumption)

Comment: @M.M Doesn't matter for strict aliasing rule purposes. Even if `uint8_t` is the same as `char` it is not excepted from strict aliasing as `char` is. At least that's the last state of the standard that I have remember.

Comment: @Voo character types are exempted from strict aliasing , this includes typedefs which target a character type

Comment: @M.M. So the idea is: If `uint8_t` is simply implemented as a typedef for `unsigned char` then the compiler is required to treat it identical and it can't apply any optimisations? I'd assumed since it is not guaranteed to be a character type the compiler didn't have to consider it for strict aliasing.

Comment: There is never any semantic difference between a type, and a typedef for that type

Answer (score 8):

You can extract bytes with [*bit shift* and *logical and*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic):

```
uint32_t value = mcu_read(pin);
uint8_t byte_0 = (value >> 24) & 0xFF;
uint8_t byte_1 = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
uint8_t byte_2 = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
uint8_t byte_3 = (value) & 0xFF;
```

Comment: Much better than c-style casts. Just add `const auto` in front.

Comment: @Vorac what are you suggesting exactly with `auto` ?

Comment: My mistake, forget it.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint32_t value = 0xAABBCCDD;
    //-------------------------------
    //byte3 | byte2 | byte1 | byte0 | 
    //-------------------------------
    uint8_t byte_0 = (uint8_t)value; //truncation according to casting rules
    printf("first byte: %x\n",byte_0);
    value>>=8; //right shift will result in the following bytes:
    //-------------------------------
    // garbage | byte3 | byte2 | byte1 | 
    //-------------------------------
    uint8_t byte_1 = (uint8_t)value;
    printf("second byte: %x\n ",byte_1);
    value>>=8;
    //etc...
}
```

output:

```
first byte: dd
second byte: cc
```